# vue composition api get typescript unable to type computed value

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to get a computed value in the composition api in vue so I have the following code:

```ts
setup() {
  const store = useStore();
  const spaUrls = inject<SpaUrls>('spaUrls');
  const azureAd = inject<AzureAd>('azureAd');
  const account: AuthenticationAccount = computed<AuthenticationAccount>(() => store.state.authentication.account);

  watch(() => account, (newValue, oldValue) => {
    if (oldValue.loading && !newValue.loading && !newValue.hasAccount) {
      // no account so redirect to unauthenticated page
      window.location.href = spaUrls.accessDenied;
    }
  });

  store.dispatch('authentication/authenticate', azureAd);
},
```

However it's failing to compile with the following errors:

> Type 'ComputedRef' is missing the following properties from type 'AuthenticationAccount': hasAccount, loading

If I use

```
const account = computed<AuthenticationAccount>(() => store.state.authentication.account);
```

It then fails with the following errors:

> Property 'loading' does not exist on type 'ComputedRef'
> Property 'hasAccount' does not exist on type 'ComputedRef'

How do I type the `account` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the computed ref has a `.value` property which is the typed variable.  I changed my code to the following to make it work:

```ts
const account = computed<AuthenticationAccount>(() => store.state.authentication.account);

watch(() => account.value, (newValue, oldValue) => {
  if (oldValue.loading && !newValue.loading && !newValue.hasAccount) {
    // no account so redirect to unauthenticated page
    window.location.href = spaUrls.accessDenied;
  }
});
```

As commented, I can also use

```
watch(account, (newValue, oldValue) => {
  if (oldValue.loading && !newValue.loading && !newValue.hasAccount) {
    // no account so redirect to unauthenticated page
    window.location.href = spaUrls.accessDenied;
  }
});
```

Comment: It should have been `watch(account` without a function to unwrap it automatically